# Send and receive text between Arduino Mega 2560 and C# via ENC28J60

Tags: arduino-mega, c#

I'm working on an Arduino project that sends and receives text to/from a C# application via ENC28J60 in a LAN network. Whenever C# sends a request to Arduino (In text), Arduino responds to it by sending also a text. What is the best way to do this? I'm newbie in network programming (Or whatever it's called). Thanls in advance :)

Comment: Use a TCP socket. Give the Arduino a static IP address, run a TCP server, and have the C# application open the connection as a TCP client.

Comment: @tttapa: you mean ENC28J60 is useless here ?

Comment: No, you need the ENC28J60 to connect the Arduino to the LAN. TCP is a network protocol that works on top of the physical connection that's established by the ENC.
[This could be useful](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap05%20-%20Network%20Protocols.html) (it was written for the ESP8266, a WiFi chip for Arduino, but the principle is the same.

Comment: https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip/tree/master/examples       found this on github. I think its what youre talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TCP or UDP protocols.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DhcpChatServer

You can use free UDP, TCP port listener sofwares for Windows, Linux etc.. for testing your setup.

For C# development:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038943/simple-udp-example-to-send-and-receive-data-from-same-socket

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182751/server-client-send-receive-simple-text

Comment: The netcat/ncat/nmap familiy of tools is also handy for those tests. They run in Linux and Windows.